# Maximum independent set $\leq$ Minimum edge cover

Tags: graph-theory

How can we prove that, for a connected graph, the maximum independent set is not larger than the minimum edge cover? Thanks.

Comment: No two vertices in an independent set may be covered by the same edge.

Comment: What is your **personal** work on the subject ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If graph $G$ is connected, every vertex has at least one edge, unless it consists of a single vertex (an exceptional case where there is no edge cover).

Suppose $S$ is an independent set and $E$ is an edge cover.  Then for each vertex $v\in S$ there exists at least one edge $e\in E$ incident with $v$.

By definition of independent set no two $u,v \in S$ have a common edge in $E$.

Therefore $|S| \le |E|$.